# Try to call a function in Insert Mode, but it does not with inoremap

Tags: vim

I try to switch from Insert mode to Cmd-line mode and call a function.

```
function Fun()
    echo 'Hello'
endfunction
```

It works in Normal mode

```
noremap <F3> :call Fun()<CR>
```

It DOES NOT work in Insert mode

```
inoremap <F3> <Esc>:call Fun()<CR>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with 'inoremap'?

Comment: Works for me. Is there any error message?

Comment: Try using an [`<expr>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-arguments), which jives a bit better with function references. Add something like `inoremap <expr> <F3> Fun()`. In theory the behavior shouldn't be different from what you have, but who knows.

Comment: No, error, when I press <F3>, it just put <F3> on my buffer,

Comment: That should work just fine. Try using a different left-hand side, e.g. `:inoremap ,` try with `vim --clean` (so no other plugin interferes), and check that the mapping somehow isn't undefined / overridden by a buffer-local mapping: `:verbose inoremap <F3>`

Comment: Remove everything from vimrc file and add the two mappings:  noremap and inoremap only.  it DOES works. but there is still long way to go to figure out where is the "conflict or error" with my 4000+ lines vimrc file.

Comment: Actually it works right now with both maps. noremap and inoremap. I think there is issue on MacVim when you reload the vimrc file. It does not clean the data in MacVim sometimes. When vimrc is reloaded, it does not clean up all the cache. sometimes I have to restart my MacVim.

Comment: Okay, that information (vimrc reload) was missing from the question. As it's now solved, and unlikely to help others, please delete your question.

Comment: I did reload my vimrc file but MacVim does't clean up all the cache I believe.